# Rescan intellisense when conda environment is updated in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have just started using vscode for Python (ML) development. One thing I am unable to figure out is how to set vscode's intellisense refresh if the conda environment is updates.

e.g. Created a new workspace with a python interpreter from a conda environment. The `environment.yml` as conda and pip packages. In the middle of my work, if I update the yml file and update the conda environment with `conda env update -f environment.yml` I want vscode to update its intellisense and the workspace as well so that I don't get symbol/import not found errors from the newly installed package. I know that with PyCharm you could set it such that the symbols would be reloaded.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but there is a command to reload the window, which has the effect of reloading the Python extension and rescanning the libraries. Open the command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then start typing "reload". The option you want is called "Developer: Reload Window"